# A better way to do batch inserts with Core Data?

Tags: json, macos, shell, core-data, insert

I'm trying to find the best way to insert large amounts or records using Core Data.

I have tried two approaches and I am wondering if there's a better way. Here are the two scenarios I have tried:

**Preconditions**

The structure of the data to be inserted is the following:

- **Entities**: Package, Product
- **Relationships**:

  - A package can contain one or more products
  - A product can be in only one package

The data to be imported is in formatted as JSON and it's in plain text files. I have one file with the list of all Packages (i.e., a list of ids, names) and one file with the list of Products per Package (i.e., a list of package id, product id, product name)

**Scenario 1**

```
Load the Packages' JSON into an NSArray
Load the Products' JSON into an NSArray
For each Package in Packages array 
  Create Package entity
  Filter Products array using Package Id using NSPredicate
  Create Product entity and associate with current Package
  Save Managed Object Context
```

**Scenario 2**

```
Load the Packages' JSON into an NSArray
Load the Products' JSON into an NSArray
// insert all Packages first
For each Package in Packages array 
  Create Package entity
  Save Managed Object Context

// insert and associate all Products
For each Product in Products array
  Fetch Packages with package id == current Product's package id
  Create Product entity and associate it with the fetched Package
  Save Managed Object Context
```

I would like to know of any better strategy to load large amounts of data to my storage.

I'm not really happy with any of the two methods since both of them are synchronous inserts and lock my app, I'm currently reading how to make asynchronous inserts but I haven't quite get it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, concurrency: do the inserting in a child context and call

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:]
```

You can notify the UI of changes via NSNotification or via the fetched results controller delegate methods.

Second, import strategy: I think both your approaches are fine. It really depends on the data which approach is faster. However, watch out for these optimisations:

1. Save in batches. Keep track of the entity count and save if a batch amount is full. Experiment until you find the fastest solution. Start with a few hundred entities (e.g. 500), but the ideal number might be 2000. Do not save the context at each iteration in the loop.
2. In the child context, switch off the undo manager. Read up on this in the Core Data Programming Guide, "[Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)". (Edit: Apple has since removed this information.)

Comment: apple link is dead, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mikael Thanks for pointing this out. I think Apple has removed this.